# How to get the default bucket name in Firebase Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to get the default bucket in Firebase from a function. It appears there was recently a change in the SDK and I can't find information on retrieving it anymore. I've tried a million things my current code looks like this and returns an empty string.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});

export const processVideo = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket.name;

  functions.logger.log("***************Bucket Name****************", bucket);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) suggests that you're supposed to provide that value to the SDK when you initialize it.  The SDK doesn't just know it without being told.

> You can specify a default bucket name when initializing the Admin SDK. Then you can retrieve an authenticated reference to this bucket. The bucket name must not contain gs:// or any other protocol prefixes. For example, if the bucket URL displayed in the Firebase console is gs://bucket-name.appspot.com, pass the string bucket-name.appspot.com to the Admin SDK.
>
> ```
> initializeApp({
>     credential: cert(serviceAccount),
>     storageBucket: '<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com'
> });
> ```

So, you have to get the value from the Firebase console and use that to initialize the SDK.

Also, you need to use a method called `bucket()`, not a property.  The API documentation says it returns a [Bucket](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html) object.

```
admin.storage().bucket()
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the information is stored in an environment variable but not imported into the admin tooling directly. So the best way I have found to prepare your environment to serve the default bucket name is as follows:

```
const firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG!);

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  storageBucket: firebaseConfig.storageBucket,
});
```